# Prevent multiple instances winform

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I've got three forms, Form1, Form2, Form3. I need to naviage between this 3 forms, like

From Form1 i need to open Form2 and close Form1 and I do it like this:

```
        Form2 myForm = new Form2(user_form1); // Initialize Form2
        this.Hide(); // hide Form1 -> This doesn't hide everytime
        this.Close(); // close Form1 -> This doesn't close everytime
        myForm.ShowDialog(); // open Form2
```

but sometimes Form1/Form2/Form3 doesn't want to hide and close, next Form is open but previous form is opened too ( but I can't click on it and do anything ).

What Can i do to prevent it? Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is unclear, is it `this` or `user_form1` that is appearing? I can't see how the code you have would make `this` reappear

Comment: What's the .net framework you use?

Comment: I asked because, for me everything gets closed when executing the above..

Comment: Better you just hide it and prevent this.close();

Comment: oops.. I've just saw you passing form2 as parameter.. Sorry

Comment: then it depends upon what you're doing on the second form's constructor

Comment: If you can put its code

Comment: so it can depends what I'm doing with the parametr in next form?